# How to make the movement of the circles smoother?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to make the movement of the three randomly generated circles smoother. Can anyone help me with that? Thank you in advance :) Here is my current code:

```
import tkinter
from time import sleep
from random import randrange


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, color):
        a = randrange(250)
        b = randrange(250)

        self.color = color
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(a,b,a+40,b+40, fill=self.color)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.id, 5,15)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x400")
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack()

circle1 = Circle('red')
circle2 = Circle('yellow')
circle3 = Circle('blue')

while(3):
    canvas.update()
    sleep(1)
    circle1.move()
    circle2.move()
    circle3.move()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say smoother, do you also mean for them to traverse the canvas quicker?

Comment: Dont use sleep(1), lower that amount and it will be smoother

Comment: No, they shall cross the canvas in the same temp, but not so choppy :) @temp123

Comment: if you divide the sleep(1) amount by 10 for example to (0.1) and do the same with canvas.move(self.id, 0.5,1.5), the speed will be the same, but the movement will be ten times smoother (10 times more movements per second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tkinter.after` instead of `sleep`, and let the mainloop do its work, instead of a `while loop` and `canvas.update()`.

something like this:

```
import tkinter
from random import randrange


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, color):
        a = randrange(250)
        b = randrange(250)

        self.color = color
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(a,b,a+40,b+40, fill=self.color)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.id, 1, 1)

def move_circles(circles):
    for circle in circles:
        circle.move()
    window.after(10, move_circles, circles)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x400")
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

circle1 = Circle('red')
circle2 = Circle('yellow')
circle3 = Circle('blue')

circles = [circle1, circle2, circle3]

move_circles(circles)


window.mainloop()
```